# libgdx blurred 2d graphics

Tags: android, graphics, libgdx, 2d

I am still getting to this problem, and i am feeling like my head is going to blow. Lets say, that i have this code for drawing a texture i created.

```
public MainMenuScreen(TheSpring game) {
    this.game = game;
    //camera for interface
    guiCam = new OrthographicCamera(1020, 640);
    guiCam.position.set(1020 / 2, 640/2, 0);
    //buttons
    play = new Button(10, 120, 400, 300, AssetLoader.play);
    highscores = new Button(460, 10, 82, 102, AssetLoader.highscores);
    sound = new Button(10, 10, 72, 72, AssetLoader.soundEnabled);
    sound.AddTexture(AssetLoader.soundDisabled);
    if (!Settings.soundEnabled)
        sound.SwitchTexture();
    help = new Button(120, 160, 80, 15, "Help", Color.WHITE);
    //enable buttons
    play.Enable(true);
    highscores.Enable(true);
    sound.Enable(true);
    help.Enable(true);
    //touchpoint for unproject
    touchpoint = new Vector3();

}`
```

The texture i created for play button is also 400x300.
The problem is, that when i try to run this "app" my textures are blurred.
The Button is my class, and I am using its drawing method.

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch batcher) {
    if (enabled){
    if (text != null) {
        AssetLoader.ComicFont.setColor(clr);
        AssetLoader.ComicFont.setScale(ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight);
        AssetLoader.ComicFont.draw(batcher, text, x, y + height);
    }
    if (texture != null) {
        batcher.draw(texture, x, y, width, height);
    }
    }

}
```

And the result is this (please don't judge me for my drawing skills, its only testing version)
[image: http://prntscr.com/5u2l1y]

For example, on the right side of button, there should be also black line, and lines should be straight. Can you please help me? :)

Comment: maybe this answer does not have to do with your question, but maybe could look over path9 can start here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches maybe you can help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, i have read the article, and it could be it, but i believe, that everybody who is trying to draw something in libgdx with Spritebatch and orthographicCamera, is not using this ninepatch method. I am just trying to draw texture, which is holding its ratio e.g.: texture 140x140, and i want to have button 70x70 with this texture on it. The result is the same as the printscreen in the main article.

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution can be setting your texture filters to Linear
By default they are not linear.
try this out

```
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear,TextureFilter.Linear);
```

Comment: Hell yeah, it helped, it is still not that pure i expected, but i believe it is caused by too thin lines in created texture. Thanks man!

Comment: the small difference you are having is maybe because of scaling of image done by you